# XCode is not compiling files and freezing the system

Tags: xcode, macos

I am facing this issue in both XCode v9 and XCode v10. When I hit run button, It compiles some files but suddenly It gets stuck. I opened the activity manager to see what went wrong. I observed this : 
[image]

CLANG is taking too much memory. does anyone know what's going on here? Is it a bug? or i did something wrong?

Comment: have to try to clean drive data and quit Xcode and run again this will be fine

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: plz verify my answer

Answer (score 1):

have to try to clean drive data and quit Xcode and run again this work  will be fine